# Sparql use filter with selecting invidual

Tags: sparql, protege

I want to retrieve all movies that actor play in. I'm not sure how to specify for which actor(individual in protege) I want results. Below code returns empty table.

```
PREFIX f: <http://imdb.com/movie.owl#>

SELECT ?title
WHERE {
    ?movie a f:Movie .
    ?movie f:Title ?title .
    ?actor a f:Actor .
    ?actor f:playsIn ?movie .
    FILTER(?actor = "Actor_1")
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OWL individuals are identified by IRIs, thus, you have to use the full or prefixed IRI in the query and not a string literal:

```sql
PREFIX f: <http://imdb.com/movie.owl#>

SELECT ?title
WHERE {
    ?movie a f:Movie .
    ?movie f:Title ?title .
    ?actor a f:Actor .
    ?actor f:playsIn ?movie .
    FILTER(?actor = <http://imdb.com/movie.owl#Actor_1>)
}
```

### Update

As @Joshua Taylor correctly pointed out, if SPARQL 1.1 is supported you should use the `VALUES` feature which is probably more what is intended here compared to a `FILTER`:

```sql
PREFIX f: <http://imdb.com/movie.owl#>

SELECT ?title
WHERE {
    VALUES ?actor { f:Actor_1 }
    ?movie a f:Movie ;
           f:Title ?title .
    ?actor a f:Actor ;
           f:playsIn ?movie .

}
```

Comment: Or, to promote the ever useful **values**, since the intent isn't really to *filter* so much as to only retrieve certain values in the first place: `values ?actor { <http://imdb.com/movie.owl#Actor_1> } ?actor a f:Actor ...`.

Comment: Right, I also like the `VALUES` feature. I'll try to use more SPARQL 1.1 features in the future.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I'm wondering whether the third triple pattern is really necessary resp. helpful here. I mean it's a triple and doesn't contribute to the rest of the query. What do you think?

Comment: You mean `?actor a f:Actor_1`? Yeah, since the value of ?actor is already known,  it won't provide any additional data. But, it will cause the query to return no results if Actor_1 doesn't have that expected type, so it so may have a purpose.  The query is essentially "if Actor_1 has this particular type, then get me these related values".

Answer (score -1):

You don't need a filter in this case. You can just include the individual in a triple pattern:

```
PREFIX f: <http://imdb.com/movie.owl#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?title
WHERE {
    ?movie a f:Movie .
    ?movie f:Title ?title .
    ?actor a f:Actor .
    <http://imdb.com/movie.owl#Actor_1> f:playsIn ?movie .
}
```

This query is not just shorter but will have better performance when run against a bigger data set.

And of course, you don't need the whole URI in case you declared the prefix:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?title
WHERE {
    ?movie a f:Movie .
    ?movie f:Title ?title .
    ?actor a f:Actor .
    f:Actor_1 f:playsIn ?movie .
}
```

Comment: 1. Most query engines are able to replace the URI inline, thus, performance shouldn't matter 2. Now it happened exactly what the query engine would do for you, you forgot to set the URI also for the third triple pattern variable `?actor`, thus, your current query has a useless triple pattern that selects all actors. 3. The third triple pattern is useless at all. :D 4. Cheers.

Comment: This isn't equivalent. The other answer captures the intent: "?actor a f:Actor . ?actor f:playsIn ?movie . FILTER(?actor = <http://imdb.com/movie.owl#Actor_1>)" With your solution, ?actor can be a different individual.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, indeed I have missed the triple asking for `f:Actor_1` to be an `f:Actor`, in which case using VALUES, as you suggested, is better. But I still believe that it's better not to use FILTER.